# How to sequentially animate menu elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I really love the way Jacob's Creek resolved their mobile website, I especially liked the mobile menu. How can I create a similar menu where elements appear after their siblings (and disappear as such)? I'd like to apply this universally on the menu, so if the user taps on a submenu/dropdown menu, the current items disappear sequentially and the next ones appear sequentially as well?

I wouldn't like to manually add delays through css since that would  make it unscalable. I need something I can reuse on other elements.

http://www.jacobscreek.com/gbl/about-us/

Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the relevant bits are:

```
.nav__item-wrapper > * {
  transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1),opacity .5s cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1);
}
```

And then for each item in the menu they set a incrementing animation time:

```
.nav-level--opened .nav__item-wrapper:nth-child(1) > * {
  transition-delay: .12s;
}
.nav-level--opened .nav__item-wrapper:nth-child(2) > *  {
  transition-delay: .16s;
}
// etc.
// all the way up to 20 with a delay of .88s
```

Since their mobile menu only shows 4 or so menu items you don't really need more than that, but it's in there.

Scalability on the delay isn't a concern, there's no way you're gonna have a menu that has more than 20 items. At that point, you have other problems.